# PythonのSeleniumでProxyを使ったらERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES

Tags: python, python3, google-chrome, selenium

PythonのSeleniumでChromeにプロキシオプションを付けて起動したのはいいのですが、`get`メソッドで何かしらのサイトにアクセスするとChromeに`ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`とでてしまいアクセスできません。

ヘッドレスモードでも通常起動でも、シークレットモードの有無も試しましたがだめでした。

プロキシはhttp://buyproxies.org/で契約しているもので、
* USERID
* PASSWORD
* SERVER IP
* PORT
が発行されます。
これらを使って

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://user_id:password@server_ip:port")
```

というようにオプションを付けました。
また、

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://server_ip:port')
options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=user_id:password')
```

のような形も試しましたがだめでした。

buyproxiesのChrome拡張機能でプロキシを試したらちゃんと接続できました。

Seleniumのバグでしょうか？

解決策や考えがありましたら教えてください。お願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/139613

Comment: すみません、ここを使うのがはじめてなもので、よくないことであれば削除いたします。

Comment: いいえ、禁止されていませんし、その必要はございません。回答しようとする人への情報提供ですのでお気になさらず。metaがご参考になれば幸いです。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/

Comment: 拝見しました、なるほどですね。ナレッジとしてうまく機能させるために質問者が正しく保守をしていくべきだということですね。ありがとうございます。